# How do I disable or redirect a php page unless its hot-linked?

Tags: redirect

I have a page called club.php. I want to disable people from being able to see my webpage if they type in www.mysite.com/club.php unless they are linked from another page. I have a page where you need to enter a password to access this.

I'm hoping I can simply drop code into my pages (javascript or something?)

Answer (score 0):

There is an HTTP header called `Referer`, which contains the URI of the site from which the request to your site originated from. You can read the content of this header in PHP via `$_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]` (see http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php).

But please be aware that you can't rely on that this header field is set or not, so testing against the content of the header is not a serious security measure for protecting a particular page from beeing viewed from unauthorized visitors. You can set/unset the value of the header to any arbitrary value with your Browser or Addon.